# Material-UI DataGrid Width Issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to get the DataGrid to only be the width of the rows without setting a containing div width?

I have tried `disableExtendRowFullWidth={true}` to help, but this only does the rows. The containing DataGrid is still full wide.

Here's my current code example - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-issue-forked-j720c?file=/src/Demo.js

Comment: i believe it's not possible as the default width for the DataGrid component is 100% form it's container , but you can set the every column width as the Docs here :
https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/columns/

Answer (score 2):

you can force the size of the Datagrid using makeStyles for example, even do more awesome stuff like adding gradient colors etc.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({

 dataGrid: {
    width: "640px"
  }
});
```

add the above variable outside your function even in another file and import it,
then add the hook useStyles in your function and attach it to de DataGrid using className.

```
export default function Demo() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <DataGrid
      autoHeight={true}
      disableExtendRowFullWidth={true}
      columns={columns}
      rows={rows}
      className={classes.dataGrid}
    />
  );
}
```

This will help you control the size, whatever keep in mind that's a fixed size, so it will not be responsive, use % units for example in order to achieve some flexibility.
Hope to help!
Good luck!

BONUS!!
Version colored just for fun:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  dataGrid: {
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)",
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: "white",
    height: 48,
    padding: "0 30px",
    boxShadow: "0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)",
    width: "640px"
  }
});
```

[Colored grid with fixed width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9iLT.png)

SANDBOX:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-issue-forked-c0n6i?file=/src/Demo.js:1304-1596